# in python, self does not mean instance?

Tags: python

I just make a foo class to explain what I mean:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, fakevalue):
        self.fv = fakevalue

    @staticmethod
    def make_a_foo():
        return Foo(2)

    def try_change_foo_value(self):
        self = Foo.make_a_foo()
        print "in change function, self.fv:", self.fv

if(__name__ =='__main__'):
    foo_instance = Foo(1)
    print "foo_instance.fv:", foo_instance.fv
    foo_instance.try_change_foo_value()
    print "foo_instance.fv:", foo_instance.fv
```

I expect:

```
foo_instance.fv: 1
in change function, self.fv: 2
foo_instance.fv: 2
```

But the result is:

```
foo_instance.fv: 1
in change function, self.fv: 2
foo_instance.fv: 1
```

We can see the self value has already changed, but the instance value does not.
Why? And how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, `self` is a pointer to the caller instance. Though you change the pointer in `try_change_foo_value`, it is just like changing a parameter in a function: it has no effect outside the method.

To clarify this, you can consider

`a.try_change_foo_value()` as shorthand for `Foo.try_change_foo_value(a)`. This should make it obvious that when you change `self`, you are changing a *local* variable, while `a`, the caller, remains unchanged.

To fix it, you should do

```
def try_change_foo_value(self):
    self.fv = 2
```

but as mgilson points out, it is more Pythonic to just say `foo_instance.fv = 2`.

If you want to actually change the value of `foo_instance` (rather than just `fv`), you should do that elsewhere, not in a method (which makes little conceptual sense).

Comment: Note that it's really not idiomatic in python to write a function which just changes the value of an attribute.  *Usually* it is more clean to just change the attribute directly:  `instance.fv = 2` rather than `instance.change_fv(2)`.

Comment: @mgilson Thanks for pointing that out, you're absolutely right. I've updated to reflect.

Answer (score 1):

`self` is just a variable.  For regular methods (e.g. not decorated with @staticmethod or @classmethod ...), the object that gets passed in is the instance.  However, within the function, you can rebind `self` to whatever you want, but the changes won't be kept outside of the function because assignment just makes a new reference to the object on the right hand side -- and unless you return that reference or store it on some object with broader scope, it will go out of scope when the function ends never to be heard from again (since you no longer have a reference/handle to it).

Consider regular functions:

```
def foo(x):
    x = 2

a = 1
foo(a)
print a #prints 1, not 2
```

This is really no different.

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the container "self" inside of the method try_change_foo_value.  Remember that self is being passed in as a parameter which means that you can change the reference inside of the variable self; but you cannot change the reference that the caller passed to you.  Think about in Java.

```
public void changeIt(Foo foo) {
    foo = new Foo(2);
}
```

if I call

```
Foo bar = new Foo(1);
.changeIt(bar);
```

I can expect bar to still be the "new Foo(1)."

Comment: "think about in Java" -- I'd rather not ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In `try_change_foo_value`, `self` starts out as the instance, but you change it on assignment. You can check this by printing the `id` of `self`.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, fakevalue):
        self.fv = fakevalue

    @staticmethod
    def make_a_foo():
        return Foo(2)

    def try_change_foo_value(self):
        print 'Originally, id(self) = %s' % id(self)
        self = Foo.make_a_foo()
        print 'After assignment, id(self) = %s' % id(self)
        print "in change function, self.fv:", self.fv

if __name__ =='__main__':
    foo_instance = Foo(1)
    print "foo_instance.fv:", foo_instance.fv
    foo_instance.try_change_foo_value()
    print "foo_instance.fv:", foo_instance.fv
```

Note the `id`s.

```
foo_instance.fv: 1
Originally, id(self) = 4299779608
After assignment, id(self) = 4299779680
in change function, self.fv: 2
foo_instance.fv: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple rule about assignment in Python. Assigning to a name in Python **always** just makes that name now refer to whatever object you just assigned to it. It **never** actually alters whatever object the name referred to before the assignment.

A simple consequence of this is that in the line `self = Foo.make_a_foo()`, it is *completely irrelevant* what `self` was before that. The fact that we're talking about classes and instances has no bearing on this. Whatever `self` was before, we now just have the name `self` referring to the new `Foo` object.

Remember, a *name* is just a handle that lets you get at an *object*. A given object can be referred to by 0, 1, or many names at any given moment in time. Assignment is an operation that affects names, not objects. There's no way you can alter an object by changing what names refer to it.

```
foo_instance = Foo(1)
print "foo_instance.fv:", foo_instance.fv
foo_instance.try_change_foo_value()
print "foo_instance.fv:", foo_instance.fv
```

When the above calls `foo_instance = Foo(1)`, it causes the name `foo_instance` to refer to a new object. When you call `foo_instance.try_change_foo_value()`, that same object gets given an additional name `self` within the scope of the method. When you change that name to refer to a new object, it has no effect on the original object, *or* on the name `foo_instance` which is still referring to that original object.

This is a very very good thing! Otherwise whenever you called a function and passed it some objects, all the assignments the function makes to its own local variables would be changing what your variables are referring to!